# Xcode 4.3 / iOS 5.1

Tags: xcode4.3, ios5.1

I want to run my app on the iPad...I upgraded to Xcode 4.3 and iOS 5.1 and the app doesn't work anymore. The strange thing is that the app don't reach the entry point, the main method is not called. Have you got any ideas what the reason could be?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSLog(@"test main"); //not visible in debugger


}
```

I know it is not much information but I don't know what info I should give

Comment: Is there an error?  What are the symptoms?

Comment: there is no error...just a black screen and no debug information

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your `NSLog` call into your AppDelegate.  Put it into the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method.  The reason you can't `NSLog` in main is that the core foundation libraries have not yet been loaded there.